# Retrieve DB objects by id field in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to retrieve Instance object in another view by it's id which has been passed by a hidden input field from template, but couldn't get the object.

Here's my files:

**BuildImage.html**

```
{% block content %}
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" id="dockerForm">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-user bigicon"></i><label for="package">Docker Image Tag Name:</label></span>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input  type="text" name="tagName"  id="tagName" placeholder="e.g node_image/istiogui" class="form-control" required>
                                <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="{{ id }}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xl-12 text-center">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-info"><a href="/gui" style="color:white">Back</a></button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-info">Build</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
</form>
```

> {{ id }} is working as I have placed it at another place in this template.

**models.py**

```
class Instance(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='instances')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    serverFile = models.TextField(default='', blank=False)
    jsonPackageFile = models.TextField(default='', blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-created_at']


class ImageModel(models.Model):
    tagName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    id = models.ForeignKey(Instance, primary_key=True)
```

**views.py**

```
class BuildImage(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'instances/BuildImage.html', {})

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pathlib.Path("mydir").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        dockerfile = """ 
        FROM node
        # Create app directory
        RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
        WORKDIR /usr/src/ap

        # Install app dependencies
        COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
        RUN npm install

        # Bundle app source
        COPY . /usr/src/app

        EXPOSE 8080
        CMD [ "npm", "start" ]"""
        cFile = open("mydir/dockerfile", "w")
        cFile.write(dockerfile)
        cFile.close()
        the_form = forms.BuildImageForm(request.POST)
        if the_form.is_valid():
            data = the_form.cleaned_data
            instance_id = data['id']
            obj = Instance.objects.all(id=str(instance_id))
            title = obj.name
            code = obj.serverFile
            package = obj.jsonPackageFile
            cFile = open("mydir/"+ title, "w")
            cFile.write(code)
            cFile.close()
            cFile = open("mydir/package.json", "w")
            cFile.write(package)
            cFile.close()
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^create/$', views.CreateInstance.as_view(), name='create'),
url(r'^buildImage/$', views.BuildImage.as_view(), name='buildImage'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try, in your view, change this line,

```
obj = Instance.objects.get(id=int(instance_id))
```

Comment: it throws another error,                                                                                       `File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IGui/instances/views.py", line 60, in post
    obj = Instance.objects.all(id=int(instance_id))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Instance'
[22/Jul/2017 05:35:06] "POST /user/instance/buildImage/ HTTP/1.1" 500 14104`